# How optimal launching angle is affected by mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, projectile, simulations, drag

I'm writing a code to calculate the maximum optimal angle for motion under linear drag and how it's affected by mass. It appears that for the most part this angle is independent of mass and not of initial velocity, which makes sense to me. However, i found that when i put very small masses into my range <1E-7 kg, the angle begins to decrease. Overall the maximum launching angle to produce the largest horizontal range tends to zero as mass tends to zero. I'm wondering why this would be, or if this should be happening at all. Does this have something to do with the drag force or shape of the trajectory for very small particles? Does drag behave differently? Overall, I'm just very confused by this result and hoping to find some answers.

Comment: It would help if you gave all the parameters and initial conditions you used. Indeed, a range of values gives rise to the behavior you observe.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 4 things that might be affecting the calculations in your simulation.

1. You mentioned linear drag. This only occurs at for low velocities where the air flow is laminar. For normal velocities, the drag force is a function of $v^2$ and not just $v$.
2. You may not have allowed for the fact that for objects with the same density, the cross section of an object that has 1/2 the mass of another object will have 1/4 the cross sectional area of the larger mass. If you are not allowing for this, you are applying a disproportionately larger drag to the lower mass objects, because drag is function of cross sectional area.
3. The analytical solutions for projectile motion with Newtonian drag are very difficult to determine and it is most likely you are doing a numerical simulation with finite discrete time steps and this only produces an approximation of the real situation. For very small masses like the ones you are suggesting, the computation errors can be exaggerated.
4. Computers do not have infinite accuracy. They have limited decimal places they can calculate to and for very small (or very large) numbers, rounding errors can exaggerate the error in the final result. Are you using single precision or double precision (or long double) floating point numbers?

Comment: I suspect the machine precision is the culprit. 1e-7 is about the value of the single precision epsilon and the square root of the double precision epsilon.

Comment: @JohnathanGross the machine precision (epsilon) is a relative error. Without knowledge of the other values, it is difficult to make a diagnosis.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 there is certainly something else going on to explain why the optimal angle is independent of mass (which should not be the case). But the sudden change of behavior at really small masses does make sense if a mass independent term (like drag) is added to a mass dependent term (like gravity). Now, decreasing mass doesn't make gravity weaker, but does increase acceleration when you divide the force by the mass.

Comment: @JohnathanGross I agree. But these considerations point to a possible problem with the time step, not with numerical precision/roundoff.